# Symbolic links in php

Tags: php

I am trying to create a symbolic link in php, on linux

if i create the link manually with ln -s targetfile linkfile it works just fine

if i try

```
<?php

symlink($targetfilefullpath, $linkfilefullpath) ; 
?>
```

nothing happens, there is no link

also if i try

```
<? php
shell_exec("ln -s ".$targetfilefullpath." ".$linkfilefullpath);
?>
```

also nothing happens, there is no link

all the targetfiles and folders have chmod 777

what could be wrong ?

Comment: have u checked the logs?

Comment: where is the log that i need to check?

Comment: https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=where+php+error+log+linux